# Python capture mouse inside 3D environment

Tags: python

I'm trying to create data files for behavorial cloning in reinforcement learning and I need to capture mouse movement inside a first person 3D game. I've researched in multiple sites already and only found mouse functions (like from pyautogui and mouse libraries) that capture the mouse movement in 2D environments, like the desktop; in those cases, moving mouse on 3D envs causes starting mouse coords to be equal to final mouse coords.

Answer (score 0):

```
Forget it, got it:    

import win32api

x, y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
mouse_x, mouse_y = 0, 0
for j in range(5):
    last_x, last_y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    if (x, y) != (last_x, last_y):
        #count = count +1
        #print("Pos:, ", (last_x - x),(last_y - y))
        mouse_x += last_x - x
        mouse_y += last_y - y
            
        x, y = last_x, last_y
        #print("Mouse Movement # ", count)
    sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).